# How do I access internal network virtual hosts in Apache?

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, home-server, hosts

This might be a stupid question but I'm tired and can't find a solution.

I currently have an Apache Web Server running on Ubuntu 10.4 and I use a DynDNS service to make them accessible to the outside world via a domain and/or subdomain.

My configs currently look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin     <obscured>@<obscured>.com
    ServerName      <subdomain>.<obscured>.com
    ServerAlias     <subdomain>

    DocumentRoot    /<obscured>/<subdomain>

    <Directory />
        Options         FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride   None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /<obscured>/<subdomain>>
        Options         Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride   All
        Order           Allow,Deny
        Allow           From All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog    ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.$host.log
    CustomLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.$host.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine from access outside of the network and all subdomains resolve to the correct directory.

The problem I am having is with accessing a subdomain over my internal network.

I can access the Web Server using the server's IP address: `http://192.168.1.123/` but this always takes me to the same virtual host and I don't know how to distinguish between different virtual hosts (different subdomains).

Ideally I would like to access the same subdomains using `http://<subdomain>/` where `<subdomain>` is the same as the subdomain attached to the external domain name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, if you use the IP address of the server, you will be taken to the first virtual instance in the list.

I just add entries to my local hosts file that use the virtual server names.

Some xDSL routers (eg: Draytek's) will allow you to use URLS that refer back to sites hosted on the local LAN - this is called DNS loopback - so another 'fix' is to change the router. This can be a viable choice for, say, a business, where it's an easier to manage solution than updating all the local hosts files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the hostname resolves to the expected IP address, and that Apache is actually listening on that IP.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question for clarification. It works fine externally.

Comment: What is the private IP?  Make sure Apache is listening on that too.

Comment: Updated again, I can access it using the IP directly but I don't know how to distinguish between different vhosts running different subdomains.

Comment: Hint:  Check your "Listen" directive in the main httpd.conf file -- this needs to cover everything you need to serve on (specifying port 80 without an IP address should catch everything though).

Comment: The "ServerName" directive will take the main one.  If you have additional hosts, then add a "ServerAlias" directive after that to support the additional ones in the same VirtualHost stanza/container.

Comment: I tried adding `ServerAlias <subdomain>` but still nothing.

Comment: Which IP address is your hostname resolving to?  Is your VirtualHost actually configured to handle that IP address?